# Android Compose - How to remove the space above and below the Switch

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-switch, android-compose-switch

I have `Row` with two components, `Text` and `Switch`, after adding the `Switch`, I see the space above and below. I want the heigh of `Switch` is fit to UI height.

I use `padding(0.dp)` but it is not working.

How to remove that?

This is my code:

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Red),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "This is a text",
            modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Yellow)
        )
        Switch(
            checked = false,
            onCheckedChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(0.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Blue)
        )
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

The `Switch` as many other components has a **minimum touch target size** (`48.dp`) for accessibility. It is applied with the **`minimumInteractiveComponentSize`** modifier.It will include extra space outside the component to ensure that they are accessible.

You can check in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).minimumInteractiveComponentSize()):

> Reserves at least `48.dp` in size to disambiguate touch interactions if the element would measure smaller.
> https://m2.material.io/design/usability/accessibility.html#layout-and-typography
>
> This uses the Material recommended minimum size of `48.dp` x `48.dp`, which may not the same as the system enforced minimum size. The minimum clickable / touch target size (`48.dp` by default) is controlled by the system via ViewConfiguration and automatically expanded at the touch input layer.

You can override this behaviour applying `false` to the `LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement`. If it is set to `false` there will be no extra space.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {

        Switch(
            checked = switchState,
            onCheckedChange = { switchState = !switchState },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(0.dp)
                .background(color = Teal200)
        )
    }
```

[image]

**Note:** `LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement` requires at least
M2 `1.4.0-alpha04` and M3 `1.1.0-alpha04`. Before you can use **`LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement`** in the same way.

Comment: It's very detailed. Thank for your answer.