# Why Material 3 Icon/Button sizes are abnormally huge by default?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-jetpack-compose, material3

I recently learnt briefly about material 3 in compose & implemented it in the current app I'm building for learning purposes (google calendar clone). In google calendar app, which I guess follows material 2, the size of buttons and switches seem normal. But with material 3 in my app, everything seems abnormally huge. Is it how material 3 is supposed to be? I chose to make a clone because I wanted a good UI reference. I guess I shouldn't have used material 3 for this app. What are your thoughts on the default sizes in M2 VS M3?

I've attached the same screen I tried to replicate from google calendar app.

[image: Google calender android app]

[image: Same screen in my app (material 3 - jetoack compose)]

I tried reducing the padding with contentPadding parameter in Button/TextButton composables. But it didn't work outm

Comment: It doesn't depends on the padding. The `Switch` as many other components has a minimum touch target size (`48.dp`) for accessibility. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75406686/android-compose-how-to-remove-the-space-above-and-below-the-switch/75408239#75408239

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are difference in size and shape of both `M2` and `M3` design, also as you can see the design of `switch`, both looks quite different.

> This is due to the fact that the two design systems and respective
> libraries differ significantly in terms of their UX/UI designs and
> Compose implementations.

Google also recommends not to migrate from `M2 to M3 compose` unless you have migrate your app design `M2` to `M3`.

> Your app may use a design system, such as one created using Figma. In
> such cases, we also highly recommend that you or your design team
> migrate it from M2 to M3 before starting the Compose migration. It
> doesn’t make sense to migrate an app to M3 if its UX/UI design is
> based on M2.

More details can be found on : [Migrate M2 to M3 Design](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#when-migrate)